# How to show / hide a configurable product's child product based on custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a configurable product, which has 4 child products. I want to show the child products to the end customer's product view page, based on a specific attribute value in the child products. (e.g 'Hide child from product page' set to 'true'). So if one of those 4 product has this attribute value set as true, then only 3 options will be visible on the product page, despite of that product being in stock, and enabled.

Disabling the child product does exactly this , but I am looking for a possibility of doing this without disabling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code as per my understanding I add below code. `hide-from-product-page` replace your attribute code.

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $block */

$_product    = $block->getProduct();
$_attributes = $block->getAllowAttributes();
$_jsonConfig = $block->getJsonConfig();
$_rendered   = [];
?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)) :?>
    <div class="field configurable required">
        <label class="label" for="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Options') ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>" class="super-attribute-select" data-mage-init='{"Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable":{"attributes":{"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>":{"selected":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getSelectedAttributes())) ?>","template":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml($_template) ?>","prices":<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig()->getConfigurablePriceList() ?>}}}'>

            <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) : ?>
                <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($_attribute->getOptions() as $_option) : ?>
                    <?php $_selectionPriceValue = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('option_value')->getValue(); ?>
                    <option data-calculator-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getData('calculator_type') ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValueIndex() ?>"<?php echo $block->getIsDisabled() ? ' disabled' : '' ?>>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option->getLabel()) ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_selectionPriceValue, true) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Get the selected options
        var selectedOptions = [];
        $('.super-attribute-select').each(function() {
            selectedOptions.push($(this).val());
        });

        // Hide options based on attribute value
        $('.super-attribute-select').each(function() {
            var optionSelect = $(this);
            optionSelect.find('option').each(function() {
                var optionValue = $(this).val();
                var optionText = $(this).text();
                var hideOption = false;

                // Check if the option's corresponding product has the attribute set to true
                // Adjust the condition based on your attribute code and value
                if (optionValue !== '' && selectedOptions.indexOf(optionValue) === -1) {
                    var product = optionSelect.closest('.product-info-main').find('.product-id-' + optionValue);
                    if (product.length && product.data('hide-from-product-page') === true) {
                        hideOption = true;
                    }
                }

                if (hideOption) {
                    optionSelect.find('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').hide();
                } else {
                    optionSelect.find('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if any queries.

**`Thanks`**

Comment: Just to confirm , this is for the page `module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` ?

Comment: yes, you need to add code there.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below solution for the same:**

**Create a Plugin**

Create a file in your custom module, for example:

```
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml:
```

**Here is the code for di.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="hide_child_products" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\HideChildProducts" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Create the Plugin Class:**

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

class HideChildProducts
{
    public function afterGetUsedProducts(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
    {
        // // Implement your custom condition here
        foreach ($result as $key => $product) {

            $productId = $product->getId();
            if ($this->shouldHideChild($productId)) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    // Implement your custom condition function
    private function shouldHideChild($productId)
    {
        // I have used static condition here. You can modify the condition as per your requirements.
        if ($productId == 2025) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please replace **YourVendor** and **YourModule** with your actual vendor and module names.

**Clear Cache:**

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

I hope this resolves the issue. If you encounter any further challenges or have additional questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on the details I shared on my question, this is indeed a perfect solution. But I am using a marketplace module, where the product owner _(who is a customer in magento with seperate customer group)_ can enable / disable the product. For this, the owner has to see the disabled product , so he/she can enable it in future.